# Kerberos - obtaining the krbtgt's secret in order to perform Golden Ticket attack

Tags: kerberos

As far as I know, in order to create a Golden Ticket, the attacker needs to obtain the krbtgt's password's hash, which is not a trivial task. My question is: is it possible to find the krbtgt's password by getting a legitimate TGT (encrypted with the krbtgt's password's hash) from the Authentication Server and cracking it, just like in a classic Kerberoasting attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically? Sure. It's just a brute force attack.

Practically? No, probably not. It's a brute force attack against a key derived from a randomly generated password that ends up being a hundred plus characters long in the easy case, or a randomly generated key that's 16-32 bytes long.

Comment: Thank You! All of the sources I came across did not mention that method (even in theoretical way), so I started to think that I am missing something important in the whole Kerberos mechanism.